# Method-level validation in Spring 3.2.3 with Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.final

Tags: spring, hibernate-validator

I have enabled method level validation in service class. However I got `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` during startup of the application. Anyone know the workaround solution for this issue:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/validator/method/MethodConstraintViolationException
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor.afterPropertiesSet(MethodValidationPostProcessor.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    ... 55 more
```

Comment: You've probably got the wrong jars on the classpath - is `org.hibernate.validator.method.MethodConstraintViolationException` still in that package for 5.0.0.Final ?

Comment: May be my question is not clear. org.hibernate.validator.method.MethodConstraintViolationException is deprecated and no longer exist since hibernate validator 5.0.0.final. The issue i am facing right now is Spring framework keep complaining about NoClassDefFoundError during application startup when I define the following in spring context: <bean id="methodValidationPostProcessor" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor"/>

Comment: I know the issue will be solved if I switch back to version 4.3.1.final but I would like to know the workaround solution that works for version 5.0.0 onwards.

Comment: AFAIK Hibernate 5+ support will be added in Spring 4. You are stuck with 4.x.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hibernate 5 custom integration will be supported only with the upcoming Spring 4 (https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10466).

If you really want to use Hibernate 5, you will need to use it as standard JSR 303 bean validation provider with the standard message interpolation mechanism (i.e. no integration with `MessageSource`, but standard `ValidationMessages.properties`).